# MVC Music Store ASPNET MVC Tutorial issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, frameworks, entity

I've been having some problems after following the Microsoft Music Store tutorial in regards to the shopping cart order completion phase, more specifically I think I have an Entity Framework issue and I am struggling to figure out where the problem lies, please refer to the guide.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-8

My problem, after I create the Order in the database, which works fine, the solution then attempts to create an OrderDetail entity which also works fine, but when everything has finished running the Order does not link to the OrderDetail, the OrderDetail part remains nullified so I am unable to iterate through the items in the order at a later date, my models are as follows.

Order.cs

```
public partial class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

OrderDetail.cs

```
public class OrderDetail
{
    public int OrderDetailId { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int MenuItemId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public virtual MenuItem MenuItem { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

MenuItem.cs

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public int MenuItemId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int MenuCategoryID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Image URL")]
    [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    public string ImageURL { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Price")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public int Order { get; set; }

    public bool Visible { get; set; }
}
```

The basket method which creates the OrderDetail and stores it in the database..

```
 public int CreateOrder(Order order)
    {
        decimal orderTotal = 0;

        var cartItems = GetCartItems();
        foreach (var item in cartItems)
        {
            var orderDetail = new OrderDetail
            {
                MenuItemId = item.MenuItemId,
                OrderId = order.OrderId,
                UnitPrice = item.MenuItem.Price,
                Quantity = item.Count
            };
            // Set the order total of the shopping cart
            orderTotal += (item.Count * item.MenuItem.Price);

            db.OrderDetails.Add(orderDetail);

        }

        // Set the order's total to the orderTotal count
        order.Total = orderTotal;

        // Save the order
        db.SaveChanges();

        // Empty the shopping cart
        EmptyCart();

        // Return the OrderId as the confirmation number
        return order.OrderId;
    }
```

Everything works fine except the association between the Order and the OrderDetails, when viewing the Orders the OrderDetails key is null when it should contain a list of type OrderDetails.

Please can someone offer some advice as I am going out of my mind trying to fix this.

I have already tried using [ForeignKey] annotations and [Key] but these failed to resolve my issue.

Comment: Can you show the code that is retrieving the Order from the DB?